# CPLEX C++ constant constraint

Tags: constants, constraints, cplex

I am making a CPLEX model with C++, and I need a function like:

```
IloConstraint f(...){
  IloConstraint constr;
        
  if(condition1){
    constr = (x+y >= 1);
    return constr;
  }
          
  if(condition2){
    constr = false;
    return constr;
  }
        
  constr = true;
  return constr;
}
```

I think that I succeded in creating a true and false constraints by

```
constr = (x==x);  and
constr = IloNot(x==x);
```

I assume that this approach is not very optimal because it adds extra conditions and variables. Is there a more optimal and more readable way to do this? Something like

```
constr = IloConstraint(IloFalse); ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IloConstraint(IloFalse)` will not work since this will be interpreted as `IloConstraint((IloConstraintI*)0)` (`IloFalse` just expands to the literal 0 (zero)), which will create a constraint without implementation.

There is no literal for a true or false constraint. You can go without extra variables if you do something like `IloExpr(env, 1) == IloExpr(env, 1)` (and `!=` for the false constraint). Another option for a constant true constraint would be use an empty `IloAnd` or an empty `IloOr`.

However, just going with `x == x`, `1 >= 2` or things similar to that seems a lot more readable to me. Additional expressions should usually not pose a problem. The engine will remove those in preprocessing.

Another option would be to use `IloCplex::ifThen()` to create a conditional constraint. Maybe this is even more readable then your function that returns a constraint.

Comment: 1>=2 returns error. Regarding IloCplex::ifThen(),  I am trying to optimize the model, so all IfThen's are checked by C++ before executing CPLEX.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. By `1 >= 2` I meant `IloExpr(env, 1) >= IloExpr(env, 2)` (similar to what I indicated in my answer). If you just write `1 >= 2` then this will just evaluate to `false`, so essentially the same as `IloFalse`. If you wrap both number in an IloExpr then the result should be a constraint (and not just a boolean) that can never be satisfied. It might be a good idea to catch these constraints that represent constant TRUE and FALSE. That may save some memory.